# Magento 2 - How to reset XML block arguments such as CSS

Tags: magento2, layout, xml, css

I'm wondering how to unset CSS that has been set through the XML, for example:

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="navigation.sections" before="-" template="Magento_Theme::html/sections.phtml">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="group_name" xsi:type="string">navigation-sections</argument>
        <argument name="group_css" xsi:type="string">nav-sections</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

That code is from the Magento Theme module. I would like to remove the `group_css` argument in my own theme, I do not want `.nav-sections` to be added to by markup.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What about using the magic setter ?

```
<referenceBlock name="navigation.sections">
    <action method="setGroupCss">
        <argument name="group_css" xsi:type="string"></argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

Or even better, I'm pretty sure you can use :

```
<referenceBlock name="navigation.sections">
    <action method="unsGroupCss" />
</referenceBlock>
```

Alternative without using the `action` tag:

```
<referenceBlock name="navigation.sections">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="group_css" xsi:type="string"></argument>
    </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

Comment: Hmmm I used a modified version of your first version, I remember reading that we shouldn't use action if the same result can be achieved through arguments. So I replaced your action method with arguments and it worked a treat, thank you.

Comment: @Ben-Space48 yeah good point I think the action tag is going to be deprecated at some point, I've updated my answer to reflect what you pointed out

Comment: perfect i am able to add new column with above code thanks, but any idea how to remove existing column with xml file?

Answer (score 0):

I use without action tag:

```
<referenceBlock name="navigation.sections">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="group_css" xsi:type="string"/>
    </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```