# How to remove an argument's item in LayoutXML

Tags: magento2, layout, magento2.3.1

How can I remove an [argument](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html#argument)'s **item** in Magento's LyoutXML?

For instance I would like to remove `<item name="msrp_price" xsi:type="array">` from [catalog_product_prices.xml](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3.1/app/code/Magento/Msrp/view/base/layout/catalog_product_prices.xml).

In my theme's *catalog_product_prices.xml*, I've tried using `remove="true"` (see below), but it doesn't work, any ideas on how I can achieve this?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
    <referenceBlock name="render.product.prices">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="default" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="prices" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="msrp_price" xsi:type="array" remove="true">
                        <item name="render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Msrp\Pricing\Render\PriceBox</item>
                        <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Msrp::product/price/msrp.phtml</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</layout>
```

Comment: You could use the _prepareLayout() method in the block lifecycle.
Arguments are set in the $data property of the block. 
You need to extend and override the block with di for this.

Answer (score 8):

Try to set it to `xsi:type="null"`

```
<item name="msrp_price" xsi:type="null"></item>
```

Comment: Great suggestion!  This worked for me.

Comment: Working for me too

Answer (score 1):

The two ideas I have for solving this are as follows:

### Overriding with an empty item

My first attempt would be to override the item with nothing effectively emptying it.

```
<item name="msrp_price" xsi:type="array"></item>
```

### Full block override

I don't like the idea of this one but as a last resort it will work, and that is to fully override the block such as removing the core block and re-creating it without `msrp_price`. As you're creating the block you have full control over what is contained within it, but this method will result in duplicated code and potentially cause issues with patches/updates.

Slightly related post here - [Magento 2 - How to reset XML block arguments such as CSS](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/118108/magento-2-how-to-reset-xml-block-arguments-such-as-css)

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful.  The first approach did not work though, and I also don't like the 2nd approach as it removed the extensibility of the original block which a lot of Magento Modules touch

Comment: Damn it, what about emptying the child items like so: <item name="render_class" xsi:type="string"></item>
                        <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string"></item>

Comment: yep, tried that too.  It just renders it as normal

Comment: How did you managed to removed the argument in XML ? I am also facing the same situation..

Answer (score 0):

Both answers did not work for me. Setting it to a null xsi:type created a javascript error because a script (layout.js) was trying to execute the hasOwnProperty method on the null value.

What worked for me is the following:

```
<item name="msrp_price" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
    </item>
</item>
```

Now, it is probably because of my specific case, and you should probably test the methods mentioned above before you try this one since it is so specific, but since I found this thread while searching for an answer to my problem, I figured I would share my solution in case other people need it.